# Unable to Upload A File Using Web Driver In Jmeter error

Tags: performance, selenium-webdriver, jmeter, selenium-chromedriver

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZXFg.png)[image]

```
Method Invocation sendKeys : at Line: 31 : in file: inline evaluation of: \`\`import openqa.selenium.OutputType.*; import org.openqa.selenium.*; import org.op . . . '' : .sendKeys ( new String \[ \] { Target exception: org. openqa. selenium .ElementNotInteractableException: element not interactable.?
```

Could any one please help me

Answer (score 0):

1. I don't think `setText()` function [exists](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html), maybe you should use [sendKeys()](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#sendKeys(java.lang.CharSequence...)) instead?
2. As per [specification](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/#dfn-element-not-interactable)

   > A command could not be completed because the element is not [pointer-](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/#dfn-pointer-interactable) or [keyboard](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/#dfn-keyboard-interactable) [interactable](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/#dfn-interactable).

   so double check your locator and if needed use [Explicit Wait](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/#explicit-wait) to ensure that the input field can be operated
3. [Since JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use Groovy for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) so it worth considering migrating as Groovy is [more Java compatible and has nice features on top.](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)